# Making next and previous buttons that display a enemy's name and hp but hide damage

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to arrays in js. I think my code is good. this is my edits https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/1wqd4tf6/28/  .   And this is the example i pulled from to try and make it work https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/brcujoa8/  .  so basically it should scroll through enemys and hp not the damage. then previous should be disabled at index 0 and next disabled at whatever is max.

I tried that first jsfiddle link but its not turning out how i want it to.

Js/html code:

```
<button id="previous">&#8249;</button>
<span id="enemyName"></span> <span id="enemyHp"></span>
    <button id="next">&#8250;</button>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function show() { 
      var item = enemyName[currentItemIndex];

document.getElementById("enemy").innerHTML=item.itemId+":"+item.itemName
      document.getElementById("previous").disabled=currentItemIndex<=0;


 document.getElementById("next").disabled=currentItemIndex>=enemyName.length-1;

    }

var enemyName = ["rat","slime","goblin","skeleton","zombie","succubus"]
var enemyHp = [10,20,25,50,75,100]
var enemyStrength = [1,3,5,10,15,25]

var currentItemIndex = 0;




window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("previous").onclick=function() {
    currentItemIndex--;
    if (currentItemIndex<=0) {
      currentItemIndex=0;
    }
    show();       
  }
  document.getElementById("next").onclick=function() {
    currentItemIndex++;
    if (currentItemIndex>=enemyName.length-1) {
      currentItemIndex=enemyName.length-1;
    }
    show();       
  }
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var ItemCatalog = new Object();
    ItemCatalog.itemId = i;
    ItemCatalog.itemName = "a"+i;
    enemyName.push(ItemCatalog);
  }
  show();
}
```

I expect the output given the arrays i thought i set up correctly for rat and 10 hp to be displayed then previous button disabled then next button not disabled. then if u press next index number should go up by 1 then next enemy name and hp should be displayed. and so on. But at the moment it isnt working exactly like that. not working much at all.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. What is it that you're trying to show when you hit next and previous?

Comment: index 0 should display rat and 10 for hp. index 1 should show slime and 20 for hp. next and previous should switch between what is being displayed. or what index number u are on.

Comment: Sure, but are you aware that the length of your HP Array does not match the length of your enemies? Is this intentional, or how should the case be handled when you get to index 5?

Comment: that was a mistake ill fix that now

Comment: so i want each index number of a array to be tied to a enemy then i want to be able to scroll through those enemys with next and previous arrows

Comment: The array lengths were different, and you fixed it, and that really points out why _you shouldn't user parallel arrays_. Use _objects_: `{ name: "rat", hp:10, strength:1 }` -- have _only one_ array of those objects and your array lengths can never be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

- Create a Constructor that creates a **Scroller**.
- Create a Constructor called **Enemy Scroller** that extends **Scroller**
- Create a List of **Enemy Objects** out of your multiple Arrays
- Apply the List of Enemies, a Previous Button, and a Next Button to the **Enemy Scroller**

**Note:** Click *show code snippet* to see a working example

```js
// combine all our enemy arrays
function createEnemyList(enemyStats) {

// an Enemy Constructor
  function Enemy(obj) {
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.hp = obj.hp;
  this.strength = obj.strength;
  return this;
}
  var enemies = [];
  for (let i in enemyStats.name) {
  // create an Enemy and add to list
  enemies.push(new Enemy({
    name: enemyStats.name[i],
    hp: enemyStats.hp[i],
    strength: enemyStats.strength[i]
  }));
}
  // return a list of enemies
  return enemies;
}

// create a Basic Scroller Constructor
function Scroller(array) {
  var scope_this = this;
  this.data = array;
  this.currentIndex = 0;
  
  // set our index limit for disabling next
  this.indexLimit = array.length - 1;
  
  // set our flags if index is at limit
  this.prevLimit = false;
  this.nextLimit = false
  
  // "next" function
  // turn off prevLimit flag
  // if we're below limit increase index
  // return data 
  
  this.next = function() {
    this.prevLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex < this.indexLimit) {
      ++this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === this.indexLimit) {
        this.nextLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }
  
  // "prev" function
  // turn off nextLimit flag
  // if we're higher than 0 decrease index
  // return data 
  this.prev = function() {
    this.nextLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex > 0) {
      --this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
        this.prevLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }
  
  // we declare objects to hold
  // our button elements ( previous, next )
  // our output elements ( hp, name, etc )
  this.buttons = {};
  this.outputs = {};
  
  // assign an element to act as previous button
  this.prevBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.prev = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.prev());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  }
  
  // assign an element to act as next button
  this.nextBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.next = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.next());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  };
  
  // function to check if button should be disabled
  // "next" button should be disabled if at nextLimit
  // "prev" button should be disabled if at prevLimit
  this.btnCheck = function() {
    if(this.buttons.next) {
      this.buttons.next.disabled = this.nextLimit;
    }
    if(this.buttons.prev) {
      this.buttons.prev.disabled = this.prevLimit;
    } 
  }
  
  // function to output current data
  // to our output elements
  // if property exists in our data
  // ( name, hp, strength )
  // we check if we have an output element for it.
  // if we do we output data to that element.
  this.output = function(obj) {
    if(this.outputs) {
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if(this.outputs[prop]) {
          this.outputs[prop].textContent = obj[prop];
        }
      }
    }
  }
 
  // set an element as the output for a property
  this.setOutput = function(name, ele) {
  if(!name || typeof name != "string" || !ele) {
    throw Error("setOutput requires a name and element as parameters");
  }
    this.outputs[name] = ele;
  }
  
  // when setup, call init to load in first index
  this.init = function() { 
   this.output(this.prev());
  }
  
  return this;
}

// define an extended Scroller specifically for Enemies
function EnemyScroller(array, prev, next) {

  // create a new Scroller
  // assign next and prev buttons
  let parent = new Scroller(array);
  parent.nextBtn(next);
  parent.prevBtn(prev);
  
  // helper function to set outputs
  function enemyStat(stat) {
    parent.setOutput(stat, document.querySelector("output#enemy_" + stat)); 
  }
  
  // set outputs for "hp" and "name"
  enemyStat("hp");
  enemyStat("name");
  
  return parent;
}

// combine all enemy stats
var enemies = createEnemyList({
  name: ["rat", "slime", "goblin", "skeleton", "zombie", "succubus"],
  hp: [10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125],
  strength: [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 25]
});

// define our previous and next buttons
var buttons = {
  next: document.querySelector("#next"),
  prev: document.querySelector("#prev")
}


// create an Enemy Scroller
let es = EnemyScroller(enemies, buttons.prev, buttons.next);

// load in first Enemy
es.init();
```

```css
#enemy-stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#enemy-stats>span {
  flex: auto;
}

.enemy-output {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="enemy-scroller">
  <h4>Enemy Scroller</h4>

  <section id="enemy-stats">
    <span>Enemy Name: <output id="enemy_name" class="enemy-output"></output> </span>
    <span>Enemy HP: <output id="enemy_hp" class="enemy-output"></output> </span>
  </section>
  <section id="enemy-scroller-btns">
    <button id="prev"><</button>
    <button id="next">></button>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation:

---

A **Scroller** is an Object that uses an Array and Scrolls back and forth through the Array by calling the methods ***next*** and ***prev***.

It keeps track of whether or not it's at the minimum( index **0** ) or the maximum( index **array.length - 1** ) and sets a flag( **nextLimit**, **prevLimit** ) when the **current index** is equal to either.

It contains two Internal State Objects:

- **buttons**: keeps track of defined *next* and *prev* buttons

  { 
    next: HTMLElement,
    prev: HTMLElement 
  }
- **outputs**: keeps track of what properties should be output to what elements

  { 
   name: HTMLElement,
   hp: HTMLElement,
   prop: HTMLElement
  }

---

It has internal methods for managing the above

- **prevBtn**(*HTMLElement*): takes an *element* and adds a *click* event handler.

  - This handler calls *Scroller.output* with the returned data from *Scroller.prev*
- **nextBtn**(*HTMLElement*): takes an *element* and adds a *click* event handler.

  - This handler calls *Scroller.output* with the returned data from *Scroller.next*
- **setOutput**(*name as string*, *HTMLElement*): takes a *property* name and an *element* and assigns it to Internal *Scroller.outputs*

  - When the *Scroller.output* method is called, any *property* in the passed data that matches a *property* in *Scroller.outputs*, that specified output *element* displays the *value.

As an example:

```
// set new outputs for our Scroller
Scroller.setOutput("lettuce",  document.querySelector("#lettuce_output"));
Scroller.setOutput("bacon", document.querySelector("#bacon_output"));

// output data
Scroller.output({ 
   lettuce: "two leaves",
   bacon: "as much as possible",
   tomato: "two slices"
 });
```

The above code will output *"two leaves"* to the **#lettuce_output** element, *"as much as possible"* to the **#bacon_output** element, and nothing else since no other outputs were defined.

---

### A Scroller Constructor

```
// create a Basic Scroller Constructor
function Scroller(array) {
  var scope_this = this;
  this.data = array;
  this.currentIndex = 0;

  // set our index limit for disabling next
  this.indexLimit = array.length - 1;

  // set our flags if index is at limit
  this.prevLimit = false;
  this.nextLimit = false

  // "next" function
  // turn off prevLimit flag
  // if we're below limit increase index
  // return data 

  this.next = function() {
    this.prevLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex < this.indexLimit) {
      ++this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === this.indexLimit) {
        this.nextLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }

  // "prev" function
  // turn off nextLimit flag
  // if we're higher than 0 decrease index
  // return data 
  this.prev = function() {
    this.nextLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex > 0) {
      --this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
        this.prevLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }

  // we declare objects to hold
  // our button elements ( previous, next )
  // our output elements ( hp, name, etc )
  this.buttons = {};
  this.outputs = {};

  // assign an element to act as previous button
  this.prevBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.prev = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.prev());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  }

  // assign an element to act as next button
  this.nextBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.next = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.next());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  };

  // function to check if button should be disabled
  // "next" button should be disabled if at nextLimit
  // "prev" button should be disabled if at prevLimit
  this.btnCheck = function() {
    if(this.buttons.next) {
      this.buttons.next.disabled = this.nextLimit;
    }
    if(this.buttons.prev) {
      this.buttons.prev.disabled = this.prevLimit;
    } 
  }

  // function to output current data
  // to our output elements
  // if property exists in our data
  // ( name, hp, strength )
  // we check if we have an output element for it.
  // if we do we output data to that element.
  this.output = function(obj) {
    if(this.outputs) {
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if(this.outputs[prop]) {
          this.outputs[prop].textContent = obj[prop];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // set an element as the output for a property
  this.setOutput = function(name, ele) {
  if(!name || typeof name != "string" || !ele) {
    throw Error("setOutput requires a name and element as parameters");
  }
    this.outputs[name] = ele;
  }

  // when setup, call init to load in first index
  this.init = function() { 
   this.output(this.prev());
  }

  return this;
}
```

Once we have the **Scroller** Constructor, which allows us to easily create a generic Array Scroller and set our outputs for our data, we can simply extend this in a separate Constructor called **Enemy Scroller** that is specific to our needs.

---

### An Enemy Scroller Constructor

```
// define an extended Scroller specifically for Enemies
function EnemyScroller(array, prev, next) {

  // create a new Scroller
  // assign next and prev buttons
  let parent = new Scroller(array);
  parent.nextBtn(next);
  parent.prevBtn(prev);

  // helper function to set outputs
  function enemyStat(stat) {
    parent.setOutput(stat, document.querySelector("output#enemy_" + stat)); 
  }

  // set outputs for "hp" and "name"
  enemyStat("hp");
  enemyStat("name");

  return parent;
}
```

The **EnemyScroller** Constructor takes an array of *enemies*, an element to use as a *next* button, and an element to use as a *prev* button.

You'll notice that we create a helper function that takes a *property name* and explicitly grabs an output element with an id of `enemy_propertyName`.

We do this because we **know** where we want the outputs to go, and that all enemies have three properties, `hp`, `name`, and `strength`. Since we don't care about `strength`, we simply don't set an output for that property.

This means that **Scroller** is generic, but **Enemy Scroller** is explicit. That's fine because the amount of code *in* **Enemy Scroller** is very little. If we ever need to change it to include the **strength** property, we can do so very easily and without altering **Scroller**.

The last thing we need to do is create a list of enemies.

---

### Creating a List of Enemies

Your current code is workable, but it's redundant with its constant loops. If all your Arrays are the same length it would be better that we transform each Enemy into its own object that contains all three of its properties( **strength**, **hp**, and **name** ).

First we house our collective enemy data in an object instead of keeping each array in Global Scope:

```
  let enemies = {
     name: ["rat", "slime", "goblin", "skeleton", "zombie", "succubus"],
     hp: [10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125],
     strength: [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 25]
   };
```

Secondly we make a function to convert the data into a single list of Enemies:

```
// combine all our enemy arrays
function createEnemyList(enemyStats) {

// an Enemy Constructor
  function Enemy(obj) {
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.hp = obj.hp;
  this.strength = obj.strength;
  return this;
}
  var enemies = [];
  for (let i in enemyStats.name) {
  // create an Enemy and add to list
  enemies.push(new Enemy({
    name: enemyStats.name[i],
    hp: enemyStats.hp[i],
    strength: enemyStats.strength[i]
  }));
}
  // return a list of enemies
  return enemies;
}
```

Third, we combine the above to make a proper enemy listing:

```
var enemies = createEnemyList({
  name: ["rat", "slime", "goblin", "skeleton", "zombie", "succubus"],
  hp: [10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125],
  strength: [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 25]
});
```

---

### Putting It All Together

The very last thing we need to do is call our **Enemy Scroller** with the appropriate data.

- Our Array of Enemy Objects
- Our Next Button Element
- Our Prev Button Element

This is done very simply with the following code:

```
// combine all enemy stats
var enemies = createEnemyList({
  name: ["rat", "slime", "goblin", "skeleton", "zombie", "succubus"],
  hp: [10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125],
  strength: [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 25]
});

// define our previous and next buttons
var buttons = {
  next: document.querySelector("#next"),
  prev: document.querySelector("#prev")
}


// create an Enemy Scroller
var es = EnemyScroller(enemies, buttons.prev, buttons.next);

// load first index to our outputs
es.init();
```

**Note:** **Scroller.init** simply loads the data at the first index( **0** ) into any specified outputs.

--
**Recap:**

- Scroller takes `data`, manages the `current index`, the `disabled` properties of any specified buttons, and putting data in our specified `outputs` when `next` or `prev` is called.
- EnemyScroller creates a Scroller with *enemies*, specifies what elements to use as the `next` and `prev` buttons, and specifies what *properties* ( `hp` and `name` ) should be output to what elements (**output#enemy_hp**, **output#enemy_name**).
- createEnemyList takes an object with all of your arrays( `hp`, `name`, `strength` ) and returns an array of individual enemy objects with the properties `hp`, `name`, and `strength`

---

### Result:

```js
// combine all our enemy arrays
function createEnemyList(enemyStats) {

// an Enemy Constructor
  function Enemy(obj) {
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.hp = obj.hp;
  this.strength = obj.strength;
  return this;
}
  var enemies = [];
  for (let i in enemyStats.name) {
  // create an Enemy and add to list
  enemies.push(new Enemy({
    name: enemyStats.name[i],
    hp: enemyStats.hp[i],
    strength: enemyStats.strength[i]
  }));
}
  // return a list of enemies
  return enemies;
}

// create a Basic Scroller Constructor
function Scroller(array) {
  var scope_this = this;
  this.data = array;
  this.currentIndex = 0;
  
  // set our index limit for disabling next
  this.indexLimit = array.length - 1;
  
  // set our flags if index is at limit
  this.prevLimit = false;
  this.nextLimit = false
  
  // "next" function
  // turn off prevLimit flag
  // if we're below limit increase index
  // return data 
  
  this.next = function() {
    this.prevLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex < this.indexLimit) {
      ++this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === this.indexLimit) {
        this.nextLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }
  
  // "prev" function
  // turn off nextLimit flag
  // if we're higher than 0 decrease index
  // return data 
  this.prev = function() {
    this.nextLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex > 0) {
      --this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
        this.prevLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }
  
  // we declare objects to hold
  // our button elements ( previous, next )
  // our output elements ( hp, name, etc )
  this.buttons = {};
  this.outputs = {};
  
  // assign an element to act as previous button
  this.prevBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.prev = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.prev());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  }
  
  // assign an element to act as next button
  this.nextBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.next = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.next());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  };
  
  // function to check if button should be disabled
  // "next" button should be disabled if at nextLimit
  // "prev" button should be disabled if at prevLimit
  this.btnCheck = function() {
    if(this.buttons.next) {
      this.buttons.next.disabled = this.nextLimit;
    }
    if(this.buttons.prev) {
      this.buttons.prev.disabled = this.prevLimit;
    } 
  }
  
  // function to output current data
  // to our output elements
  // if property exists in our data
  // ( name, hp, strength )
  // we check if we have an output element for it.
  // if we do we output data to that element.
  this.output = function(obj) {
    if(this.outputs) {
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if(this.outputs[prop]) {
          this.outputs[prop].textContent = obj[prop];
        }
      }
    }
  }
 
  // set an element as the output for a property
  this.setOutput = function(name, ele) {
  if(!name || typeof name != "string" || !ele) {
    throw Error("setOutput requires a name and element as parameters");
  }
    this.outputs[name] = ele;
  }
  
  // when setup, call init to load in first index
  this.init = function() { 
   this.output(this.prev());
  }
  
  return this;
}

// define an extended Scroller specifically for Enemies
function EnemyScroller(array, prev, next) {

  // create a new Scroller
  // assign next and prev buttons
  let parent = new Scroller(array);
  parent.nextBtn(next);
  parent.prevBtn(prev);
  
  // helper function to set outputs
  function enemyStat(stat) {
    parent.setOutput(stat, document.querySelector("output#enemy_" + stat)); 
  }
  
  // set outputs for "hp" and "name"
  enemyStat("hp");
  enemyStat("name");
  
  return parent;
}

// combine all enemy stats
var enemies = createEnemyList({
  name: ["rat", "slime", "goblin", "skeleton", "zombie", "succubus"],
  hp: [10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125],
  strength: [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 25]
});

// define our previous and next buttons
var buttons = {
  next: document.querySelector("#next"),
  prev: document.querySelector("#prev")
}


// create an Enemy Scroller
let es = EnemyScroller(enemies, buttons.prev, buttons.next);

// load first index to our outputs
es.init();
```

```css
#enemy-stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#enemy-stats>span {
  flex: auto;
}

.enemy-output {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="enemy-scroller">
  <h4>Enemy Scroller</h4>

  <section id="enemy-stats">
    <span>Enemy Name: <output id="enemy_name" class="enemy-output"></output> </span>
    <span>Enemy HP: <output id="enemy_hp" class="enemy-output"></output> </span>
  </section>
  <section id="enemy-scroller-btns">
    <button id="prev"><</button>
    <button id="next">></button>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

### Why do it this way instead of Building a single Enemy Scroller?

It's best to make things that are extensible and maintainable. If, at any other point in your application, you need to scroll through other lists of data, you no longer need to code out an explicit case.

For instance, as an example, if you need to create a `loot` system or a `shop`, you can simply extend `Scroller`.

This is an example of A Magic Shop ( also viewable [here](https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/BaBmyMy) ):

```js
function Scroller(array) {
  var scope_this = this;
  this.data = array;
  this.currentIndex = 0;
  
  this.indexLimit = array.length - 1;
  
  this.prevLimit = false;
  this.nextLimit = false

  
  this.next = function() {
    this.prevLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex < this.indexLimit) {
      ++this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === this.indexLimit) {
        this.nextLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }
  
  this.prev = function() {
    this.nextLimit = false;
    if (this.currentIndex > 0) {
      --this.currentIndex;
      if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
        this.prevLimit = true;
      }
    }
    return this.data[this.currentIndex];
  }
  

  this.buttons = {};
  this.outputs = {};
  

  this.prevBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.prev = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.prev());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  }
  

  this.nextBtn = function(ele) {
  this.buttons.next = ele;
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scope_this.output(scope_this.next());
      scope_this.btnCheck();
    });
  };
  

  this.btnCheck = function() {
    if(this.buttons.next) {
      this.buttons.next.disabled = this.nextLimit;
    }
    if(this.buttons.prev) {
      this.buttons.prev.disabled = this.prevLimit;
    } 
  }
  

  this.output = function(obj) {
    if(this.outputs) {
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if(this.outputs[prop]) {
          this.outputs[prop].textContent = obj[prop];
        }
      }
    }
  }
 
  this.setOutput = function(name, ele) {
  if(!name || typeof name != "string" || !ele) {
    throw Error("setOutput requires a name and element as parameters");
  }
    this.outputs[name] = ele;
  }
  
  this.init = function() { 
   this.output(this.prev());
  }
  
  return this;
}

function makeShopItem(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  return this;
}


function ShopScroller(items, next, prev, buy) {
  var parent = new Scroller(items);
  parent.nextBtn(next);
  parent.prevBtn(prev);
  
  parent.setOutput("name", document.querySelector("#item_name"));
  parent.setOutput("price", document.querySelector("#item_amount"));
  parent.purchase = function() {
    var purchased = parent.data.splice(parent.currentIndex, 1)[0];
    parent.output(parent.prev());
    if(!parent.data.length) {
      
      parent.output({name: "Sold Out!", price: 0})
      buy.disabled = true;
    }
    parent.indexLimit--;
    alert(purchased.name + " was purchased!");
    return parent;
  };
  if (buy) {
    buy.addEventListener("click", parent.purchase);
  }
  parent.init();
  return parent;
}
var buttons = {
  next: document.querySelector("#shop_next"),
  prev: document.querySelector("#shop_prev"),
  buy: document.querySelector("#shop_purchase")
}
let shopItems = [
new makeShopItem("blue suede shoes", 500.50), 
new makeShopItem("Hyrule Shield", 999.50), 
new makeShopItem("Mega Buster", 100)
];

let ss = new ShopScroller(shopItems, buttons.next, buttons.prev, buttons.buy);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#item-stats {
  background: rgba(24,24,24,1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#shop-scroller {
 background: rgba(0,0,255,.3);
  text-align: center;
 font-family: cursive;
 width: 300px;
background-color: #840b2a;
  color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px groove black;
}
#item-stats>span {
  flex: auto;

}
#item_name {
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red, 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0.2em blue;
}
.item-output {
  color: skyblue;  
}

.item-amount::before {
 color: rgba(250, 230, 20, .8);
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red, 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0.2em blue;
 content: "$";
}
button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="shop-scroller">
  <h1>My Magic Shop</h1>

  <section id="item-stats">
    <span>Item: <output id="item_name" class="item-output"></output> </span>
    <span>Cost: <output id="item_amount" class="item-output item-amount"></output> </span>
  </section>
  <section id="shop-scroller-btns">
    <button id="shop_prev"><</button>
    <button id="shop_next">></button>
          <button id="shop_purchase">purchase</button>

  </section>
</div>
  </div>
```

What's the difference between your **Enemy Scroller** and my **Magic Shop** ? *About twenty lines of code.*

Comment: o wow this is alot thanks. yea im kind of new at this only just started a javascript class in school. i taught myself somestuff over the past 1-2 months but nothing to this extent. only simple things.

Comment: I will look into adding this into my game thanks.  https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/1wqd4tf6/49/   i got mine fixed by  adding this near the top      var item = enemyName[currentItemIndex];
      document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML=enemyName[currentItemIndex]
      document.getElementById("previous").disabled=currentItemIndex<=0;
      document.getElementById("next").disabled=currentItemIndex>=enemyName.length-1;

Comment: but i like what you gave me i will prob use what you suggested instead